# issue with tab view at bottom and scroll view

Tags: android, tabs, android-widget

I am facing an issue with tab view at bottom and scroll view.

Actually in my application i have an activity having multiple edit boxes so that to scroll the view i have used scroll view.
But now the problem is that i have tabs at bottom so when we tap on any edit box the soft keyboard pops up and it move the whole view to upward (means the bottom tab also).
While i don't want this i just to show the keyboard over the tabs at bottom.

For reference i am attaching a screen shot also

https://picasaweb.google.com/101436805822316575664/Test#5558753509930483714

Please tell me why it is happening. and is it possible that bottom tab will not show when keypad comes in scroll view.